# Selenium send keys not working for ENTER key (Node js)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver tool for automation of my website.

I want to press ENTER key automatically using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@ng-click="today()"]')).sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
```

But I am getting error `ReferenceError: Key is not defined`

In python we have action chains to accomplish this task.
Is there any alternative in `Node js` ?

Comment: The webdriver code looks to be in Java. There is no need to be asking for specifying `node.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
Its working fine now.

```
driver.findElement((webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@ng-click="today()"]')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER);
```